# How to do an atomic custom update of a mongodb document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, transactions

I am aware that MongoDB can do atomic updates using `findOneAndModify` but this only permits basic operations like set or increment.

What I need is to apply a custom function to transform my document:

```
const updateDoc = async (event) => {
  const oldState = await db.collection(collectionName).findOne({ name });
  const newState = customFunction(oldState, event);
  await db.collection(collectionName).replaceOne({ name }, newState);
}
```

This function will be called by a system that won't wait for a resolved promise to continue working: there can be multiple synchronous calls.

Is there a way to rewrite `updateDoc` to make it atomic, so that when we do:

```
updateDoc(event1); // note the absence of await
updateDoc(event2);
```

We can be sure that the stored doc will be `customFunction(customFunction(initState, event1), event2)`?

Thanks

Comment: If you're concerned that `oldState` is something you  decide your `newState` on but `oldState` may actually not be what  is currently in the database when writing `newState` (it may actually not be what is in the database when you make your decision). The maybe the following could help: http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/2633/no-more-dirty-reads-with-mongodb/ Depending on how big you need to scale you may want to do CQRS with an event store (you never update events but use them to calculate current state and data is eventually consistent).

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually doing CQRS + event store, I have read projections that are stored in mongodb and are re-written on new events, this question is about those projections :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be a task queue, that shedules one update after another:

```
class Scheduler {
  constructor(){
    this.running = false;
    this.queue = [];
  }

  add(el){
     this.queue.push(el);
     if(!this.running) this.run();
  }

  async run(){
    this.running = true;
    while(this.queue.length) await this.queue.shift();
    this.running = false;
 }
}
```

Usable like this:

```
 const dbTasks = new Sheduler();

 const updateDoc = async (event) => dbTasks.add( _ => {
   const oldState = await db.collection(collectionName).findOne({ name });
   const newState = customFunction(oldState, event);
   await db.collection(collectionName).replaceOne({ name }, newState);
});

updateDoc(evt1);
updateDoc(evt2);
```

Comment: If Thomas concern is "dirty reads?" then would this help? Looks like he wants to get data, decide what new data is based on the data got, save new data. Somewhere between get data and save data mongodb can flush some changes to that particular document.

Comment: @hmr as far as i understand the problem is that currently its *get event1*  -> *get event2* -> *set event1* -> *set event2* and because of that the changes of event1 are not considered by event2s set. Using a queue solves this

Comment: I don't know enough about mongo but not sure if resolved write promise means that when you read immediately after it (in the task queue) you actually get the data that's just written (especially when clustered and optimized for writing). Depending on OP's needs serializing all db read/writes may not scale very well but does answer what he asked for.

Comment: @hmr im neither a mongodb expert. your point may be true but i cant realy tell